# Cannot update with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

When I run put from FastAPI docs with the following code, I get ``` 500 Error: Internal Server Error`` and the terminal shows ``` AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute ' items'```` and the terminal shows `AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'items'`.

I can create, get, delete, etc. normally, but for some reason I can't just put.

Also, if I try putting in a non-existent ID, I get a 404 error normally.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me more about it.

router

```py
@router.put('/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
def update(id, request:schemas.Test ,db:Session = Depends(get_db)):
    test= db.query(models.Test).filter(models.Test.id == id)
    if not test.first():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f'Test with id {id} is not found')
    test.update(request)
    db.commit()
    return 'updated'
```

models

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from db import Base

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'
    id = Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True,index=True)
    title = Column('title',String(256))
```

schemas

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Test(BaseModel):
    title:str
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy's `update` method on objects expects a dict. You're giving it a pydantic base model.

Pydantic's BaseModel supports a `dict()` method to [return the object's properties as a dictionary](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#model-properties). You can give this dictionary to your `update` method instead:

```
test.update(request.dict())
```

Also be aware that the `request` name is used for other things in FastAPI and might not be a good name for a route parameter. The `id` name is also a reference to a built-in Python function, so you'll usually want to name it `test_id` or something similar instead.